# Using foreach to generate an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a `$_POST` array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => ed
    [1] => smith.co.uk
    [2] => http://edsmith.co.uk/smith.jpg
    [3] => Published
    [4] => ford attenborough
    [5] => ford.co.uk
    [6] => http://fordattenborough.co.uk/ford.jpg
    [7] => Pending Approval
    [8] => greg tolkenworth
    [9] => greg.co.uk
    [10] => http://greg.co.uk/greg.jpg
    [11] => In Future
)
```

I have an array that looks like this

```
"unique_id()" => array(
     "partner_name" => array(
         "id" => $shortname."_partner_name",
         "name" => "the_partner_name",
         "desc" => "The partner's name",
         "type" => "text",
         "value" => "",
         "placeholder" => "partner name",
     ),
    "partner_url" => array(
         "id" => $shortname."_partner_url",
         "name" => "the_partner_url",
         "desc" => "Url of the partner",
         "type" => "text",
         "value" => "",
         "placeholder" => "partner url",
     ),
     "partner_logo" => array(
         "id" => $shortname."_partner_logo",
         "name" => "the_partner_logo",
         "desc" => "Logo of the partner",
         "type" => "text",
         "value" => "",
         "placeholder" => "partner logo",
     ),
     "partner_status" => array(
         "id" => $shortname."_partner_status",
         "name" => "the_partner_status",
         "desc" => "The status of the partner",
         "type" => "select",
         "options" => array("Select Option","Publish", "Pending Approval", "In Future"),
         "std" => "Select Option",
     )),
```

The posted array is held by this variable `$posted['partner_crud']` and i am trying using `foreach`

```
$u = uniqid();

foreach($posted['partner_crud'] as $key => $value){

$add_this_array = array($u => array(
         "partner_name" => array(
             "id" => $shortname."_partner_name",
             "name" => "the_partner_name",
             "desc" => "The partner's name",
             "type" => "text",
             "value" => $value,
             "placeholder" => "partner name",
         ),
        "partner_url" => array(
             "id" => $shortname."_partner_url",
             "name" => "the_partner_url",
             "desc" => "Url of the partner",
             "type" => "text",
             "value" => $value,
             "placeholder" => "partner url",
         ),
         "partner_logo" => array(
             "id" => $shortname."_partner_logo",
             "name" => "the_partner_logo",
             "desc" => "Logo of the partner",
             "type" => "text",
             "value" => $value,
             "placeholder" => "partner logo",
         ),
         "partner_status" => array(
             "id" => $shortname."_partner_status",
             "name" => "the_partner_status",
             "desc" => "The status of the partner",
             "type" => "select",
             "value" => $value,
             "options" => array("Select Option","Publish", "Pending Approval", "In Future"),
             "std" => "Select Option",
         )));
         }
```

to generate four arrays in the format as i have shown above.The problem is i am only able to produce an array with only the first value.How can i produce all the four arrays?.

Comment: Its vague what are you asking for. Can you only post the relevant code to your issue ? And post the output you getting & your expected  output ?

Comment: We don't need all your data to answer the question. Could you try to create a minimal example?

Comment: He wants a multi-level array to be created from his form submission. And I think the problem lies with the HTML too..

Comment: What i can see from your code is that in your foreach loop in the last piece of code you posted, you are redeclaring your variable $add_this_array. So you will only get what was assigned in the last iteration of the loop. You need to add $add_this_array to your result array within the loop.

Comment: why are all your `$_POST` array keys numerical?

Comment: @Rikesh i have edited the question.Its now simpler to understand.

Comment: @Scuzzy i have the form name as an array.

Comment: So you have four datasets in your post data, one is items 0 through 3, the second is items 4 through 7 and so on, correct?
Where do you get the unique id for each of those four datasets? Its not contained in the post data. If its the same for all four datasets, in which way is it unique?

Comment: I don't want any array to have a duplicate key so i am just using `uniqid()` to make sure no two keys are similar.

Comment: If you want to make sure nothing gets overwritten, you should simply append:
$arr = array();
$arr[] = arrray('a'=>'b');
$arr[] = arrray('c'=>'d');

Comment: If you array chunk the main post array into 4 is a longer route imho.I shall continue developing this and see if it works.

Comment: I don't think there is a measurable performance hit if you compare this to a readable post data structure. I would be interested in your profiling results though.

Comment: I forgot to point out that i am pretty sure that the data is valid when it is posted.For now i just want to generate the arrays and the area of data validity will be dealt with on the client side later.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unusual to have post data like that. It makes something easy hard.

If thats what you have however, you can try something like this:

```
if (!is_int(count($posted['partner_crud']) / 4))
    throw new Exception("Invalid Post data");

$result = array();
foreach($posted['partner_crud'] as $key=>$array) {
   $dataset = floor($key / 4);
   $infoType = $key % 4;
   switch ($infoType) {
       case 0: 
           $result[$dataset]['partner_name'] = array(
                'id'=> ...
                'value'=>$value,
            );
            break;
       case 1: 
           $result[$dataset]['partner_url'] = array(
                'id'=> ...
                'value'=>$value,
            );
            break;
        case 2:
             ....
        case 3:
              ....
   }
}

return array($uid=>$result);
```

You should make really sure that your post data has the right format however, and nothing gets out of order.